# How to pass a value from one class to another c# Grasshopper

Tags: c#, grasshopper

I try to pass the bool bake value from one class(attribute class) to the solve instance(buttonTest class).
I already tried several things as the Get Method and write a property without sucess.

```
namespace buttonTest
{
   public class buttonTestComponent : GH_Component
   {      
     public override void CreateAttributes()
     {
       m_attributes = new Attributes_Custom(this);
     }

   protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
   {
       Circle circle = new Circle(2.00);
      //here I want to bake       
   }

   public class Attributes_Custom : GH_ComponentAttributes
   {
       public Attributes_Custom(GH_Component owner) : base(owner) { }
       protected override void Layout()


        bool bake;


       public bool Bake
       {
           get { return bake; }
       }



       public override GH_ObjectResponse RespondToMouseDown(GH_Canvas sender, GH_CanvasMouseEvent e)
       {
           if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
           {
               RectangleF rec = ButtonBounds;
               if (rec.Contains(e.CanvasLocation))
               {
                   bool bake = true;
                   MessageBox.Show("Hello World", "Hello World", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

                   return GH_ObjectResponse.Handled;
               }
           }
           return base.RespondToMouseDown(sender, e);
       }
}

}
```

I am a beginner so I hope it is possible to understand.

Thanks to everybody

if I try to use m_attributes.Bake I get the following error message:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ndGW.png)

Comment: Why does `m_attributes.Bake` not work?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you need something like the following.

The *buttonTestComponent* class:

```
public class buttonTestComponent : GH_Component
{    
     private Attributes_Custom m_attributes;

     public override void CreateAttributes()
     {
          m_attributes = new Attributes_Custom(this);
     }

     protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
     {
         Circle circle = new Circle(2.00);
         //use m_attributes.Bake here
     }
}
```

And you leave *Attributes_Custom* class as it is.